# How to extract a closure into typealias?

Tags: swift, closures, type-alias

I'm a bit lost with typealias, the following chunk of code works fine, which I would like to refactor into using typealias.

```
NEVPNManager.shared().loadFromPreferences(completionHandler: vpnLoadHandler)

func vpnLoadHandler(_: (Error?)) -> Void {

}
```

I would like to create a typealias instead:

```
typealias vpnCompleteClosure = (_: (Error?)) -> Void

func vpnLoadHandler(complete: @escaping vpnCompleteClosure) {
}

NEVPNManager.shared().loadFromPreferences(completionHandler: vpnLoadHandler)
```

Unfortunately this doesn't compile anymore:

> Cannot convert value of type '(@escaping vpnCompleteClosure) -> ()'
>   (aka '((Optional) -> ()) -> ()') to expected argument type
>   '(Error?) -> Void'

What am I missing?

**UPDATE:**

```
open func loadFromPreferences(completionHandler: @escaping (Error?) -> Swift.Void)
```

Comment: can you please add `loadFromPreferences(completionHandler:  )` signature

Comment: Sure, I've added it, thanks

Comment: A type alias for what? Your `func vpnLoadHandler` does not take a closure argument.

Answer (score 0):

`loadFromPreferences(completionHandler:)` is expecting a parameter, `completion` that is of type `(Error?) -> Void` Your `typealias` is passing a `((Optional) -> Void) -> Void` Your error is telling you you have mismatching signatures.

That being said, you need to figure out what the signature of the top level method is. What are you calling your completionHandler on? What are you expecting to get back from it.

I have to admit Im confused as to your purpose of passing `vpnLoadHandler(complete:)` into `loadFromPreferences(completionHandler:)`

Your method will end up looking like `(((Error?)-> Void) -> Void) -> Void`

write your `typealias` as:

```
 typealias VPNCompletionHandler = (Error?) -> Void

 func vpnLoadHandler(completion: @escaping VPNCompletionHandler)
```